# How do I hide or delete "open" and "closed" statuses from a custom status group?

Tags: status, delete, custom

I've created a custom status group in EE 2.6.1. I'd like to use my own statuses (draft, ready, send, sent) and I want to remove "open" and "closed", or rename them. What's the easiest way to get rid of the default open and closed status choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete those as open is a default status parameter for channel entries. What you can do is create your custom status, and only give your client access to the custom statuses. This way Open and Close never show up.